# How do I display a surf of an image in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have an image that shows depth of the image using colors where warmer colors represent the closer parts of the image and cooler colors represent objects further away. I want to represent this image as a surf plot showing the depth. I have to do this in java but I think its easier to understand the process in Matlab first before moving on. I tried using the size of the image and plotting that but it kept giving me errors. Any help would be much appreciated.

I tried the surf function:

```
`img = imread('sample.png');
grayImage = rgb2gray(img);
surf(double(img))`
```

and got this error:

```
>> surf 
Attempt to execute SCRIPT surf as a function:
C:\Users\kuchin\Documents\MATLAB\surf.m
Error in surf (line 3)
surf(double(img))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

As seen in your comment in this own post, your problem is that you are overriding the surf function by another surf.m file you have. Dont name your matlab files with the same name that Matlab built functions. Go to `C:\Users\kuchin\Documents\MATLAB\surf.m` and name it `mysurf.m`. It will resolve your problem.

**ORIGINAL POST**

If you have a depth image (MxN) of doubles just

```
surf(img);
```

if they are uint8

```
surf(double(img));
```

Will do the trick.
Test code:

```
img=imread( 'coins.png' );
surf(double(img))
```

Outputs:

[image]

Comment: I tried this but I get an error, here is my input: 
img = imread('sample.png');
grayImage = rgb2gray(img);
surf(double(img))

and my output and error:
>> surf
Attempt to execute SCRIPT surf as a function:
C:\Users\kuchin\Documents\MATLAB\surf.m

Error in surf (line 3)
surf(double(img))

Comment: @user3748494 Do surf(double(grayImage)); If that does not work can you please post the image or a link to the image?

Comment: @user3748494 mmm the problem is then that you have a .m file caled surf.m in the directory you provided, and that file is overriding Matlabs surf function. Never name your .m files as maltab functions!!
If, for exmaple, you use another funciton (e.g. surfc()) youll see there is not a problem

Comment: I don't have enough reputation points to post an image. I tried the surfc function but am getting an error as well. What should I save it as to get rid of this overriding problem?

Comment: Ahh, I just figured it out, thank you so much Mr.Biguri!

Comment: @user3748494 in "C:\Users\kuchin\Documents\MATLAB\" you will be able to se you own .m functions. Thats the default matlab working path. Somehow you have there functions with the same name as matlab built in functions and those functions are overriding matlabs ones. Change thenames of those

Comment: @user3748494 Accept the answer then so everybody can see how to solve the problem :)